# bash scripting with screen

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I want to write a bash script that opens multiple screens and detaches them. So at the end you'll have a few screens open each running a different command.

Similar to `ssh`:

```
ssh DESTINATION "command 1; command 2;"
```

my idea was to write something like this:

```
screen -S name1 "command1"
screen -S name2 "command2"
...
```

But this doesn't work.

ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `-d -m` to the `screen` command.

Comment: can you please give an example